# Make CSS changes to osssearchresults page only

Tags: 2013, search-results, css

Is there a way to make CSS changes to the osssearchresults page without it affecting all other pages on the site?  Specifically, for this site collection the left navigation is hidden.  I want this to stay hidden, but be able to view it on the osssearchresults page (where the refiners are located).  It would be simple if I could edit the page and add a script editor, but you are unable to do that.  I also can't find the file in Designer.  Is this possible or what other options do I have?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of a way to alter a system page.

I would create a page and a new layout for Search Results. Add your CSS and JS to the layout its using.

[image]